# How to count how many times a loop has been executed? c++

Tags: c++, c++11

How to count how many times a loop has been executed my code doesn't work as I expected it,

find the primes numbers before n number input by user and display them and count how many

numbers are in total

ex.
number input lets say 7,

and there are 3 numbers before 7

so it displays 2,3,5,7 and there are 3 prime numbers before 7

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 int n, i, k;
 int counter = 0;
 bool isprime;


 cout << "Enter a positive integer n: "; 

 cin >> n;

 for(int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
 {
        isprime = true;

        for(int i = 2; i <= k - 1; i++)
            if(k%i == 0)
        {
                isprime = false;
        }

        if(isprime)
        cout << k << "\t";}



cout << "\nThere are " << counter << " primes less than " << n;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should probably increment `counter` somewhere, maybe wherever you discover a prime.

Comment: Change `if(isprime) cout << k << "\t";` to `if(isprime) { ++counter; cout << k << "\t"; }` and init counter with -1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 int n, i, k;
 int counter = 0;
 bool isprime;


 cout << "Enter a positive integer n: "; 

 cin >> n;

 for(int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
 {
        isprime = true;

        for(int i = 2; i <= k - 1; i++)
            if(k%i == 0)
        {
                isprime = false;
        }

        if(isprime)
        {
            cout << k << "\t";
            counter++;
        }
 }



cout << "\nThere are " << counter - 1<< " primes less than " << n;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, counter is never modified from its initial value. Try having it count what you want to count.

Added: ...
BTW. Prefer

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

for looping. The "i < n" is more idiomatic (easier to read) and the ++i normally will be more efficient than i++.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter your range: ";
    cin >> num;

    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for(int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++)
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(count == 0 && i != 1)
            cout << i << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This will increase the count variable every time there's a prime number.

Answer (score -1):

As said above `counter` is not incremented.

You should make a function

```
isPrime?(int n)
{ 
    int sqrt_n = sqrt(n)
    for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt_n; i++){ //You could check only to sqrt(n)
    if(n%i == 0)
    {
            return false;
    }
    }
return true;
}
```

And then you could use that function as follow:

```
int main()
{

 int n, i, k;
 int counter = 0;


 cout << "Enter a positive integer n: "; 

 cin >> n;

 for(int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
 {
    if(isPrime?(k)) {
       counter++;
       cout << k << "\t";
    }
cout << "\nThere are " << counter << " primes less than " << n;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to cache the result of sqrt(n) to avoid calculating every time.